# Redirect all images to an external server using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect the static images files on my localhost to my external dev server. 
All the images are stored in one directory. In the html they point to:`loc-site.example.com/sites/dev.site.com/images`. I would like to redirect them to `http://[ip_address]/sites/dev.site.com/images`. I did some research and tried the following:

```
  RewriteRule loc-site.example.com/sites/dev.site.com/image(.*)$ http//:111.222.333.333/sites/dev.site.com/files/images/$1
```

But this is still not working.

Also, how do I see the rewritten url? How can I test these rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your hostname as part of the pattern in a rewrite rule, only the request URI gets passed in for the matching. You want something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loc-site\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRUle ^sites/dev.site.com/image(.*)$ http://111.222.333.333/sites/dev.site.com/files/images/$1
```

[L,R=301]

You can remove the `=301` part of the flag if you don't want a permanent redirect.

Comment: I am still having issues. How do I debug the redirect?

Comment: @aresnelupin where are you getting redirected to, what are the "issues"?

Comment: Thanks. It was just not working. No redirect when I visit a page that is supposed to be redirected. After a few test and using htaccess online tester I did this and all works fine `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loc-site\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^sites/blala/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ http://11.1.1.1.1./sites/blabla/$1[QSA,L]`. I also put this in the top of my .htaccess so it does not conflict with other rewrites rules.

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts this worked for me

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^loc-site\.example\.com$ [NC]   RewriteRule ^sites/blala/(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ http://11.1.1.1.1./sites/blabla/$1[QSA,L]`
Hope this helps others.